# How to order DOM XML elements by number of attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

Is there a feasible method that allows to order elements by attribute count? I'm primarily concerned about performance.

I would like to order elements by highest to lowest number of attributes.

e.g. XML document

```
<!-- 1 -->
<element attr1="" attr2="">
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
</element>

<!-- 2 -->
<element attr1="" attr2="" attr3"">
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
</element>

<!-- 3 --> 
<element attr1="">
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
    <param name="" value=""/>
</element>
```

Correct order in this case would be 2, 1, 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most XML transformations, the best tool for the job is XSLT. The following is XSLT 2.0, but it's almost as easy in 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="element">
    <xsl:sort select="count(@*)" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:template>
```